# SQL Server tabulating survey data for every month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, server

I have a survey table with many columns but i am focusing on these 2, survey_date and over_rating. i am not sure if it is possible to be done in a single query. I am using sql server 2012. This is my sample data.

```
select survey_date, overall_rating from survey

survey_date             overall_rating
2017-01-06 15:09:51.940 6
2017-02-06 14:18:18.620 4
2017-05-07 16:03:12.037 7
2017-05-23 10:41:30.357 7
2017-05-23 10:41:30.357 5
2017-05-24 12:05:25.217 8
2017-06-01 09:03:47.727 7
2017-06-05 09:01:07.283 9
2017-06-05 09:28:12.597 6
2017-06-15 09:47:29.407 7
2017-07-06 12:10:50.003 2
2017-07-06 13:45:52.997 7
2017-08-06 14:00:35.403 5
2017-08-09 12:21:17.367 8
```

I need to count the occurrence for each rating 1-10, for each month, and sum it up. Example June 15, rating 10 have 1, rating 9 have 10, ... 
This is the result table:

```
Month           10  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   Avg Score   Total   Total >=6   CSI
June'15         1   10  20  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   8           34      34          100%
July'15         1   16  14  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   9           32      31          99%
August'15       7   6   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9           19      19          100%
September'15    0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9           4       4           100%
November'15     0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8           3       3           100%
December'15     0   7   3   4   2   0   0   0   0   0   8           16      16          100%
```

i have tried this query but is partly wrong as there is duplicate month for each rating:

```
select si.yr, si.mn, 
case when si.overall_rating = 10 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '10',
case when si.overall_rating = 9 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '9',
case when si.overall_rating = 8 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '8',
case when si.overall_rating = 7 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '7',
case when si.overall_rating = 6 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '6',
case when si.overall_rating = 5 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '5',
case when si.overall_rating = 4 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '4',
case when si.overall_rating = 3 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '3',
case when si.overall_rating = 2 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '2',
case when si.overall_rating = 1 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '1',
sum(si.overall_rating) as month_count
from
(select YEAR(s.survey_date) yr, MONTH(s.survey_date) mn, s.overall_rating
from survey s where s.status='Submitted' and s.survey_date >= '2017-01-01' AND s.survey_date <= '2017-12-31' 
group by YEAR(s.survey_date), MONTH(s.survey_date), s.overall_rating) si group by si.yr, si.mn, si.overall_rating;
```

Results:

```
yr      mm  10  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   total
2017    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   6
2017    2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   4
2017    5   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   5
2017    5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7
2017    5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8
2017    6   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   6
2017    6   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7
2017    6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9
2017    7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
2017    7   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7
2017    8   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   5
2017    8   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8
```

As you can see 5 and 6 are repeated for different rating. If anyone could tell me is it possible to be done in a single query. Thanks

Comment: Your sample data does not match up your desired output.  Please either add additional sample data or change your desired output so we know what you are working towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve here and you'll be pleased to know you are not far off.  You have the right idea in using a conditional aggregate, but you need to wrap your conditional `case` expression in the aggregate, not the other way around.  To do a conditional `count`, you can simply return `1` for a condition match and `0` for a no match and then `sum` up the result.

Doing this allows your `group by` to remain nice and simple:

```
declare @t table(survey_date datetime,overall_rating int);
insert into @t values ('2017-01-06 15:09:51.940',6),('2017-02-06 14:18:18.620',4),('2017-05-07 16:03:12.037',7),('2017-05-23 10:41:30.357',7),('2017-05-23 10:41:30.357',5),('2017-05-24 12:05:25.217',8),('2017-06-01 09:03:47.727',7),('2017-06-05 09:01:07.283',9),('2017-06-05 09:28:12.597',6),('2017-06-15 09:47:29.407',7),('2017-07-06 12:10:50.003',2),('2017-07-06 13:45:52.997',7),('2017-08-06 14:00:35.403',5),('2017-08-09 12:21:17.367',8);

select dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,survey_date),0) as [Month]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [10]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as [9]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as [8]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as [7]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as [6]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as [5]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as [4]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as [3]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [2]
        ,sum(case when overall_rating = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [1]
        ,count(overall_rating) as ScoresReturned
        ,sum(overall_rating) as TotalScore
        ,avg(cast(overall_rating as decimal(10,0))) as Average
from @t
group by dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,survey_date),0)
order by [Month];
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+------------+----------+
|          Month          | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | ScoresReturned | TotalScore | Average  |
+-------------------------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+------------+----------+
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |              1 |          6 | 6.000000 |
| 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |              1 |          4 | 4.000000 |
| 2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |              4 |         27 | 6.750000 |
| 2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |              4 |         29 | 7.250000 |
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |              2 |          9 | 4.500000 |
| 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 |  0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |              2 |         13 | 6.500000 |
+-------------------------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks so much is working! Just a qn why you put order by [Month], but the result is still not in order Jan-Feb-May....

Comment: @TommyYap  Ah apologies, updated to provide correct ordering.  The previous ordering was not correct because the `Month` column returns a text string, so `August` comes first alphabetically.  Ideally, you would simply do `dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,survey_date),0)` to get the first day of the months and return that to your presentation layer to be formatted appropriately.  In fact I'll edit my answer to do it that way instead.

Comment: oh and sorry to say the average is correct but the total is referring to the number of response not the total you did. For example in your result, June 17 total should be 4 and average will be 29/4 = 7.25 which is correct.

Comment: @TommyYap  Ah, in that case, just change the `sum` to a `count`.  Do note that your comment there contradicts your question though.

Comment: thanks is according to the results table i posted :)

Comment: @TommyYap  Edited to just include both.

Answer (score 0):

```
select si.yr, si.mn, 
case when si.overall_rating = 10 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '10',
case when si.overall_rating = 9 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '9',
case when si.overall_rating = 8 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '8',
case when si.overall_rating = 7 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '7',
case when si.overall_rating = 6 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '6',
case when si.overall_rating = 5 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '5',
case when si.overall_rating = 4 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '4',
case when si.overall_rating = 3 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '3',
case when si.overall_rating = 2 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '2',
case when si.overall_rating = 1 then count(si.overall_rating) else 0 end as '1',
sum(si.overall_rating) as month_count
from
(select YEAR(s.survey_date) yr, MONTH(s.survey_date) mn, s.overall_rating
from survey s where s.status='Submitted' and s.survey_date >= '2017-01-01' AND s.survey_date <= '2017-12-31' 
group by YEAR(s.survey_date), MONTH(s.survey_date), s.overall_rating) si group by si.yr, si.mn;
```

You must remove `si.overall_rating` in `Group By`

Comment: Have you tested this at all?  This will definitely not satisfy the requirements of this question.  This is also a very low quality answer as you have not explained *why* they should remove the `group by` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I posted late, anyway you can try this otherwise.

DATA:

```
        IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL )
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #temptable
            END

        CREATE TABLE #temptable
            (
              survey_date DATETIME ,
              overall_rating NUMERIC(22,2)
            )

        INSERT  INTO #temptable
                ( survey_date, overall_rating )
        VALUES  ( '2017-01-06 15:09:51.940', 6 ),
                ( '2017-02-06 14:18:18.620', 4 ),
                ( '2017-05-07 16:03:12.037', 7 ),
                ( '2017-05-23 10:41:30.357', 7 ),
                ( '2017-05-23 10:41:30.357', 5 ),
                ( '2017-05-24 12:05:25.217', 8 ),
                ( '2017-06-01 09:03:47.727', 7 ),
                ( '2017-06-05 09:01:07.283', 9 ),
                ( '2017-06-05 09:28:12.597', 6 ),
                ( '2017-06-15 09:47:29.407', 7 ),
                ( '2017-07-06 12:10:50.003', 2 ),
                ( '2017-07-06 13:45:52.997', 7 ),
                ( '2017-08-06 14:00:35.403', 5 ),
                ( '2017-08-09 12:21:17.367', 8 )
```

QUERY:

```
                ;
        WITH    CTE
                  AS ( SELECT   DATENAME(month, survey_date) + ' '''
                                + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(survey_date) AS NVARCHAR(4)),
                                        2) AS [Month] ,
                                ISNULL([1], 0) [1] ,
                                ISNULL([2], 0) [2] ,
                                ISNULL([3], 0) [3] ,
                                ISNULL([4], 0) [4] ,
                                ISNULL([5], 0) [5] ,
                                ISNULL([6], 0) [6] ,
                                ISNULL([7], 0) [7] ,
                                ISNULL([8], 0) [8] ,
                                ISNULL([9], 0) [9] ,
                                ISNULL([10], 0) [10],
                                Total,
                                Average
                       FROM     ( SELECT    survey_date ,
                                            COUNT(overall_rating) overall_rating,
                                            CAST(SUM(overall_rating) AS INT) Total,
                                            AVG(overall_rating) Average
                                  FROM      ( SELECT    DATEADD(MONTH,
                                                          DATEDIFF(MONTH,
                                                          0, survey_date),
                                                          0) survey_date ,
                                                        overall_rating
                                              FROM      #temptable
                                            ) T
                                  GROUP BY  t.survey_date
                                ) PVT PIVOT ( SUM(overall_rating) FOR overall_rating IN ( [1],
                                                          [2], [3], [4],
                                                          [5], [6], [7],
                                                          [8], [9], [10] ) ) P
                     )
            SELECT  [Month] ,
                    ISNULL([1], 0) [1] ,
                    ISNULL([2], 0) [2] ,
                    ISNULL([3], 0) [3] ,
                    ISNULL([4], 0) [4] ,
                    ISNULL([5], 0) [5] ,
                    ISNULL([6], 0) [6] ,
                    ISNULL([7], 0) [7] ,
                    ISNULL([8], 0) [8] ,
                    ISNULL([9], 0) [9] ,
                    ISNULL([10], 0) [10],
                    Total,
                    Average
            FROM    CTE
```

RESULT:

```
        Month                   1      2    3     4     5     6     7    8    9     10    Total       Average
        ----------------------- ------ ---- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ---- ----- ----- ----------- -------------
        January '17             1      0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0     0     6           6.000000
        February '17            1      0    0     0     0     0     0    0    0     0     4           4.000000
        May '17                 0      0    0     4     0     0     0    0    0     0     27          6.750000
        June '17                0      0    0     4     0     0     0    0    0     0     29          7.250000
        July '17                0      2    0     0     0     0     0    0    0     0     9           4.500000
        August '17              0      2    0     0     0     0     0    0    0     0     13          6.500000

        (6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Whilst you can do this, you do not get the additional totals.

Comment: @iamdave actually it can , Edited the script above :)

Comment: At that point, may as well just manually `pivot` as per my answer.